# Mitzvot distribution by categories

Tags: halacha-theory

[This site gives a nice basic infographic](https://www.sefaria.org.il/visualize/sefer-hachinukh-mitzvot) on the distribution of the 613 Mitzvot by 4 categories: positive/negative, where, who, penalty. (*I would love to have it in verbal tabular form though)*.

I'm looking for more [sites with] statistics on Mitzvos distribution by more categories, like:

1. בין אדם למקום / לחבירו
2. תמידיות / זמניות / שהזמן גרמן
3. profession dependent/independent (king, Kohen Gadol etc)
4. by performance type: thoughts, speech, actions, money etc.
5. by body parts (like [Sefer Haredim](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%A1%D7%A4%D7%A8_%D7%97%D7%A8%D7%93%D7%99%D7%9D))
6. unanimously accepted / debatable between Poskim (Rambam, Sma"g, Ramban etc)
7. and more.

*NB: Please don't argue about the legitimacy of the categories. I'm free to accept any additional division.*

Comment: I'm actually working on a site like this but it's very far from done. I hope no one beats me to it :-)